# Access 2007 Word Automation on Windows 10

Tags: vba, ms-access

I just received a new Dell XPS tablet with Windows 10 Pro version 1909 I have also have:

- one other Windows 10 XPS tablet (last year's model)
- Windows 7 Inspiron
- Surface Pro Windows 10 version 1903

My Access 2007 with Word 2007 automation runs flawlessly on the other machines, but on the new machine, I am getting an error with this line:

```
Set objWord = New Word.Application
```

The error states

> "Automation Error - Library not registered." Error 8002801d

There is a proper reference checked for Word Object Library 12.0 pointing to:

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSWORD.OLB
```

The new machine has all the latest updates, and the Office 2007 has been installed, repaired, etc. The Database has been recompiled, repaired, compacted, etc. There seems to be no way to register a .OLB file

My database application runs fine if I take out any attempt to open a Word document, and the Word 2007 program also works fine independently.  It's just the one line that's the problem: Access simply doesn't recognize Word even though there is a proper reference.

Since the application is working fine on three other computers.  What am I missing? This machine is under warranty with Dell for Premium support, but I don't see how this can be a problem with the computer because it is otherwise working well.

Comment: 1. What's the status of the reference in the **Tools** -> **References...** dialog? 2. If you open a Word document, open the VBA editor, right-click on the project in the **Project Explorer**, insert a new module, and write in the same line of code `Dim objWord As Word.Application : Set objWord = New Word.Application"; and run it, what happens?

Comment: As a note, you should develop using early binding (i.e. set a reference to the library and use `Set objWord=New Word.Application`), but deploy using late binding (i.e. remove the reference to the library and use `Dim objWord  As Object:Set objWord=CreateObject("Word.Application")`). This removes the problem of people having different versions of Word/Excel etc. on their computers.